# Time adds 5 hours to my local time before displaying

Tags: angular

I have added `today: number = Date.now();` in my angular code . but it gets the time after adding **5 hours** to my local time. Not sure what is wrong.

```
today: number = Date.now();
```

My HTML code that displays time on screen

```
<p class="date-format-layout-vertical-align">
    Printed &nbsp; &nbsp; {{ today | date: 'short' }}
</p>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `it gets the time after adding 5 hours to my local time`

Comment: Have you verified that the value of `today` is the local time, and not the local time plus five hours?

Comment: My local time is 11.10AM . It displays 4:10PM on my main report

Comment: What happens when you use new Date() instead of Date.now?

Comment: @MikeOne  - gets me the same time. No change

Comment: Right. So are you setting a locale in your Angular app somewhere?

Comment: @MikeOne am not sure what that exactly is - 
but  I have something `public locale: string = 'en-us';` in my code

Comment: @MikeOne What can I do to check whether if a locale is getting set or not. If NOT, how can I set one?

Comment: You could try to use https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate.. however, unless there is something weird going on with your setup (wrong timezone on your local machine, or some provider that forces a locale) - this should really not be needed to get it right..

Comment: @MikeOne is there a way I can somehow stick in my function in the HTML itself so that it gets the browser time automatically. ?

Comment: @MikeOne It's still getting the the UTC time for me. not sure what needed to be changed to get this working. Can you suggest something ?

Comment: Maybe there are some clues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874731/angular-6-typescript-new-date-is-created-in-utc-but-i-need-in-my-local-timezone

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Date()` instead of `Date.new()`.

When no parameters are provided, the newly-created `Date` object represents the current date and time, specified in the local time zone, as of the time of instantiation.
[Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

The `Date.now()` method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.
[Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

> Edit

You can also try to subtract the time offset and then use the pipe `{{ getDate() | date: 'short }}`

```
public getDate(): string {
    const date = new Date()
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
    return date.toISOString()
}
```

Comment: sure, let me try. Looks its getting the UTC time for me when  i am using Date.new()

Comment: No change. does the same thing